# New to Linux and need help in activating my new swapspace and mounting ext4 partition to /mnt

Tags: ubuntu, mount, swap, automounting

I am new to Linux and I am working on the configuration of my Linux OS for a project. I am using the Oracle VM Virtualbox and using Ubuntu 20.04 I added a DOS/MBR table scheme during installation and created my Ext4 and swap partitions, I ran the commands to enable my user1 to utilize sudo, and my question is how do I activate the new swap partition and and mount the new ext4 partition to /mnt making sure that the new filesystem will be mounted with every boot.

Comment: Mounting a filesystem on `/mnt` will confuse the automounter. Mount your disk elsewhere. Read `man swapon mount`  and `man -a fstab`. See `https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard`.

Answer (score 0):

You can add these two lines to your fstab file (`/etc/fstab`)

```
UUID=[UUID for partition] /mnt     ext4    defaults,noatime 0 2
UUID=[UUID for partition] swap      swap    defaults,noatime 0 2
```

You can find the UUID of the partitions by running `blkid` as root.
You can also enable swap at runtime by running as root, `swapon /dev/[swap_partition]` - can also be found using `blkid`